# What is meant by the phrase "No heroic measures"

Tags: phrases

Heard this phrase a few times not entirely sure what is meant by it.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of this site is that you have done some initial research; a simple web search turns up many pages which explain what *heroic measures* means in a medical context. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance.

Answer (score 2):

It's often used to describe a wish of a terminally ill patient that medical professionals not attempt to resuscitate them when they die.

For example, that if their heart stops, that CPR or a defibrillator not be used, or if they stop breathing that they not be placed on a ventilator.

Answer (score 0):

It really has to do with treatments from before the 19th century. People like Benjamin Rush, whose excessive bloodletting probably killed George Washington. I think the root of it has to do with its shady efficacy, and poor scientific rigor. At the core of this treatment methodology lies the idea that intense diseases must have intense treatments and risks.

I think when it is used today, it harkens back to this era and functions pejoratively. Although it typically doesn't work, I don't think it is appropriate to call cardiopulmonary resuscitation a heroic measure, unless you are attempting to discredit it as an evidence-based intervention. An intervention causing harm, even side effects like cracked ribs is not enough to deem it heroic. Trauma interventions, and AIDS or Cancer treatments are often called heroic.

Comment: A~, I can't speak to your assertion that it has to do with treatments from the XVIIIth century. I do know, however, that whether a particular treatment is considered heroic depends upon the cost benefit ratio between the damage a treatment causes, and the likelihood that the treatment will have a benefit. For an otherwise relatively healthy person who suffers a CVA (heart attack), CPR would not be a heroic measure. On the other hand, for a person with inoperable, metastasized lung cancer, CPR would be considered heroic.

Comment: MW has "of a kind that is likely only to be undertaken to save a life" as a definition of "heroic".  CPR is unlikely to be used without the intent to save a life.